# Is it possible to define relations in terms of functions?

Tags: functions, relations

The usual way is to define *relations* first, then *functions* in terms of relations.

Is it possible to reverse this, and define *functions* first, and then *relations* in terms of functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely. Given sets $X$ and $Y$, a relation is a family of functions $$\{f_i: X_i\rightarrow Y|i\in I, X_i\subset X\}$$

To interpret this in the usual definition of relations, $(x,y)$ is said to satisfy this relation iff there is $i\in I$, $x\in X_i$ such that $f_i(x)=y$.

To make it intuitive, say we want to describe father-son relation, then $f_i$ could be the $i$-th son of a father. $X_i$ has to be a susbset, as not everyone has $i$ sons.

However, in this way, we need to define an equivalence between different families of functions that essentially describe the same relation.

Or a relation is a function $f:X\rightarrow 2^Y$. And $(x,y)$ is said to satisfy this relation iff $y\in f(x)$. In this case we can assume the domain is just $X$, as if no $y$ has the relation with $x$, we may just define $f(x)=\emptyset$. In the above example, we just map a father to the set of his sons, without worrying about which son is represented by which $f_i$.

Anyway, a relation is just a multivalue function.

Comment: Using a power set like that is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Some computer languages do this.

A "relation" on sets $A_1,\dots,A_n$ is a function with domain $A_1 \times \dots \times A_n$ and codomain $\{\text{true},\text{false}\}$.
Also $A_1\times \dots \times A_n$ is the set of functions $p$ with domain  $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that $p(k) \in A_k$ for all $k$.